# Get selected data from checkbox in a PHP contact form

Tags: php

I'm using PHPmailer which is working.

But since I'm working with some checkboxes in the contact form I'm running into a problem.

I gave all of the checkboxes the same name which = `type[]` And they all have different values.
I want to target the selected values and turn that into a variable which I can then target to send in the mail.

This is the code I'm using:

```php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
if(!empty($_POST['type'])) {
    foreach($_POST['type'] as $value){
        $type = $value;
    }
}

$message = "Name: $name<br> lastname: $lastname<br> Type: $type";
```

This will give me only the last selected value. So if multiple are selected it doesn't show me.
I don't want to use a database to store the values before getting it.

Comment: How do you want the types to look in the message? You can simply `$type = implode(", ", $_POST['type']);` to get them as a string without a loop

Comment: What is your expected output? You're iterating over an array `$_POST['type']` and reassigning that value to `$type`, so in the end `$type` only has the last value. Do you want to output all values of `$_POST['type']` instead? You could change your `$message = ...` line to have `implode(", ", $_POST['type'])` instead of `$type`.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed your form be like below:

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <span>Select languages</span><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="PHP"> PHP <br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="JavaScript"> JavaScript <br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="jQuery"> jQuery <br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name='lang[]' value="Angular JS"> Angular JS <br/>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

So you can get the selected checkbox value like this one:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['lang'])) {

        foreach($_POST['lang'] as $value){
           echo "value : ".$value.'<br/>';
      }
  }
}
?>
```